# A div under a fixed div

Tags: html, css

I want to create a #necker div with the same height, and width, and to center him the same way as my #header div that fixed to top of screen.
I tried to copy the data from the #header div to #necker div and margin in down from top. Failed :(. Could you help me?

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(217, 47, 54);
  z-index: 1;
}

#necker {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 142px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(245, 210, 83);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Yakir Freed </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate1">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate2">
      <h2>About us</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate3">
      <h2>Support</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate4">
      <h2>Sales!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate5">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="necker"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div can't center the same as the menu, because the `position: fixed` casues it to ignore the default `margin` from the browser stylesheet. If you add `margin: 0` to `body` the two elements will be centered in the same spot.

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(217, 47, 54);
  z-index: 1;
}

#necker {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 142px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(245, 210, 83);
}
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
  <div class="Categories" id="Cate1">
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Categories" id="Cate2">
    <h2>About us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Categories" id="Cate3">
    <h2>Support</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Categories" id="Cate4">
    <h2>Sales!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Categories" id="Cate5">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="necker"></div>
<div class="makeitscroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly what you are not expecting from your code? If the problem is that the two div hasn't got the same width, try removing the margin and padding from the body (so 80% results in both cases in the same number of pixels).

The fixed block use the complete viewport width to calculate the 80%, instead, the #necker use the body width (using the default margin or padding that the browser is applying)

```
body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

If that's not your problem, I can't see what you need to achieve, please, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I believe below solution will help you. Thing you missed is default margin `<body>` has. Deleting it fixes the issue.

#### Key part

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(217, 47, 54);
  z-index: 1;
}

#necker {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  margin-top: 142px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(245, 210, 83);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Yakir Freed </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate1">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate2">
      <h2>About us</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate3">
      <h2>Support</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate4">
      <h2>Sales!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Categories" id="Cate5">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="necker"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. How easy and forgotten rule